# Datatable Row expansion not working with filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tablefilter, rowexpansion

I have a datatable with both row toggle expansion and filter option. On expanding, another datatable comes and that gets populated from a different table in db. when i am not filtering any value, the expansion works fine and the other datatable is getting populated. But when I am filtering and then clicking on the expand button, it's showing no records found in the second datatable.

#### xhtml code

```
<p:dataTable var="data"
                    value="#{List.trackingList}" rows="10"
                    paginator="true"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" widgetVar="trackTable"
                    emptyMessage="No entries found with given criteria">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Summary
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column style="width:16px">
                        <p:rowToggler />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="ID" style="font-size:16px;"
                        filterBy="#{data.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.id}" style="font-size:14px;" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{data.status}"
                        filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.status}" style="font-size:14px;" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Created Time" style="font-size:16px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.chkDtStamp}" style="font-size:14px;" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Created By" style="font-size:16px;"
                        filterBy="#{data.createdby}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <h:outputText value="#{data.createdby}" style="font-size:14px;" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:rowExpansion>
                        <p:dataTable var="metadata"
                            value="#{statusList.getStatusList(data.id)}">
                            <p:column headerText="Description" style="font-size:15px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{metadata.description}"
                                    style="font-size:13px;" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Status" style="font-size:15px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{metadata.status}" style="font-size:13px;" />
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Score" style="font-size:15px;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{metadata.score}"
                                    style="font-size:13px;" />
                            </p:column>

                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:rowExpansion>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: add your backing bean

Comment: i solved it. Adding @ViewScoped to the back end bean solves the problem.